# Как проверить кортеж на наименьшие число?

Tags: python, кортежи

Можно ли проверить кортеж на наименьшие число? Если да то как?
На python

Answer (score 3):

```py
k = (3, 5, 9, 2, 6, 4)
print(min(k))
```

Вывод:

> 2